# Unable to switch to another UIViewController when “Edit” UITableViewRowAction is pressed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2, uitableviewrowaction

I want my swift app to open an UIViewController (called "SecondViewController") when the UITableViewRowAction "Edit" is pressed. However, my code below doesn't do anything; when I press the "Edit" action, absolutely nothing happens.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

//Edit action
let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Edit") { (editAction, indexPath) -> Void in

    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

}

return [editAction]

}
```

How could this be solved? Is this even possible? If more information is needed, please comment.

Comment: I think the navigation controller is nil. Please add the navigation controller in the storyboard

Comment: Ha that was quite simple. Didn't know that I NEED to have a uinavigationcontroller for this to work. thanks. Put it as an answer (just copy paste) so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I have answered. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `navigationController` is nil. You can add the `navigationController` either through the `storyboard` or create it programatically and make the `ViewController` containing tableView as the `rootViewController`. This should work